# Read from file and assign as string and call function as argument

Tags: c, arrays, function, file-io, function-pointers

I try to use passing function as argument but I'm stuck. I have two questions:
First, I try to call uppercase and open .txt in tfm  Second, How can I read characters from in.txt as string and assign to char content[] ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void tfm( char str_filename[], void(*pf_convertion)( char content[]));
void uppercase(char content[]);     //converts all letters to uppercase
int main(){

    puts("-------------------------------");
    printf("tfm:\n");
    tfm("in.txt", uppercase);
    puts("-------------------------------");

    return 0;
}

void tfm( char str_filename[], void(*pf_convertion)( char content[])){

    FILE *fptr_in;

    if((fptr_in=fopen(content,"r"))==NULL){
        printf("Error reading file\n");
    }
    else{
        (*pf_convertion)(str_filename);
    }
}

void uppercase(char content[]){

    char ch;
    int st;

    for(st=fscanf(fptr_in,"%c",&ch);
        st==1;
        st=fscanf(fptr_in,"%c",&ch)){

            if('a'<=ch && ch<='z'){
                ch-=32;
                printf("%c",ch);
            }
            else
                printf("%c",ch);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Note: should prototype or declare `tfm()` before calling it in `main()`.

Comment: First, the word is "assign", not "assing". Second, the very first rule here is "one question per post". This site is designed to be a **question and answer** (Q & A) site, not a questions and answers (Qs & As) site. If you have two questions, make two posts. You can always link to the first one from your second one.

Comment: thank you @KenWhite I will pay attention.

Comment: you have misunderstood the role of each function.